# Como funcionam as bibliotecas gráficas C?

Tags: c, característica-linguagem, console, biblioteca

Como funciona as bibliotecas gráficas?

Por exemplo, o modo padrão de execução do C é o console application, como a partir disso de somente texto eles consegue criar as bibliotecas gráficas onde entende pixel ao invés de letras e caracteres? como transformam texto em imagens, vetores e etc?

Como é esse processo de entrar no modo gráfico?

Como faço para criar uma biblioteca gráfica?

Comment: Do que você está falando? Ou eu não entendi ou a premissa da pergunta está errada. Nenhum texto é transformado em imagens. Explique melhor o que você quer saber. Você quer saber como entrar em modo gráfico?

Comment: @bigown sim, editei a pergunta

Comment: Eu recomendo que use interfaces gráficas java em seus programas.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=312bRmUsRx0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Para fazer gráficos aparecerem na tela, existem várias **camadas**:

1. Os criadores das placas gráficas, placas-mãe, monitores definem uma maneira de essas partes se comunicarem. Por exemplo, setar o pino X com um bit Y, esperar tantos nanossegundos, ler os bytes no endereço Z, etc. Essas convenções podem seguir padrões como os barramentos PCI ou PCI Express, conexão com monitor VGA ou HDMI, etc. Você só vai trabalhar neste nível se mexer com hardware ou sistemas operacionais.
2. O sistema operacional possui um *driver* que controla as funcionalidades acima, de modo que os programadores de aplicações não precisem (nem possam!) se comunicar diretamente com a placa de vídeo. Você só vai trabalhar neste nível se estiver escrevendo *drivers*, sistemas operacionais, ou se estiver usando algum sistema mais primitivo, como o MS-DOS.
3. Novamente o *sistema operacional* (OS) possuirá uma *interface para programação de aplicações* (API) para acesso àquilo que o driver implementou, com syscalls (chamadas de sistema). As syscalls podem ser em assembly mesmo ou podem ser disponibilizadas no formato de uma biblioteca para uma linguagem de nível mais alto, como o C.
4. Uma biblioteca de mais alto nível ainda poderá abstrair mais a tarefa, fornecendo uma nova API mais amigável que pode ser usada da mesma maneira em diversas linguagens e sistemas operacionais.

E aí, **como se cria uma biblioteca gráfica "do zero"?** Depende de onde você põe o zero.

Se você tem somente uma placa e um processador, você vai começar do passo 2, escrevendo drivers e sistemas operacionais.

Se você tem uma placa, um processador, e também um sistema operacional, você vai começar do passo 3, usando os recursos que o sistema operacional oferece e construindo em cima disso.

O caso que eu imagino que você queira saber é esse último, quando você já tem o sistema operacional mas não consegue entender como bibliotecas como Qt, GTK+, e SDL fazem para desenhar na tela. A resposta então é: elas tomam para si a responsabilidade de falar com o sistema operacional na "língua dele", seja lá qual for (Win32? GDI+? DirectX? OpenGL? Xlib? Wayland? Syscalls diretas ao kernel do sistema operacional?).

A linguagem C, por razões históricas, provê uma maneira unificada (<stdio.h>) de tratar com arquivos de texto (incluindo aí a tela e o teclado), mas não provê o mesmo para gráficos. No fundo os dois casos passam por camadas semelhantes (biblioteca para o programador de aplicações, API do OS, driver, bits e bytes para a comunicação com os componentes do computador, até chegar ao nível da corrente elétrica que faz tudo funcionar).

Portanto é bem comum termos *uma biblioteca, que chama outra biblioteca, que chama outra biblioteca, que chama uma função dependente do sistema operacional, que chama o driver, que faz o pixel aparecer na tela*. Podemos comparar com a abertura de arquivos em C++ onde existem vários jeitos: iostream (padrão do C++), fopen (padrão do C), open (padrão POSIX), CreateFile (Win32) (os dois primeiros são de nível mais alto e os dois últimos são de nível mais baixo).

Veja estes **exemplos**:

1. A aplicação usa [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/about/) no Linux, que chama
2. [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/docs/architecture/), que usa...
3. [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) para fazer gráficos em 2D que...
4. fará o necessário para gerar os gráficos no sistema operacional usando **Xlib**, **XCB**, **Quartz**, ou **Win32**...
5. que acessará o OS com uma syscall
6. e o OS usará o driver de vídeo para enviar os pixels para a tela.

No caso do Windows, é necessário passar uma opção ao compilador ou ao *linker* para usar o "subsystem windows" e assim evitar a aparição daquela telinha preta de linha de comando. Mas deixar de fazer isso não impede o programa de criar janelas no Windows (com CreateWindowEx ou qualquer função equivalente), só ficaria mais feio para o usuário.

Note que o programador poderia também usar GTK+ diretamente, caso achasse que a wxWidgets não está oferecendo nenhuma vantagem. Mas se descer até a Xlib (ou XCB), certamente teria mais dificuldades para portar o app para Windows, ou quando o X se tornar obsoleto e todos usarem Wayland. E olha que posso ter esquecido de alguma camada na lista acima! Por exemplo, escrevendo esta resposta descobri a existência da XCB em alternativa à Xlib.

Ou então:

1. Um jogo em [SDL](http://wiki.libsdl.org/Introduction)
2. que usará chamadas às APIs **Win32** e **Direct3D** para gráficos no Windows
3. ou **Cocoa** e **OpenGL** para gráficos no Mac OS.

Lembrando que para gráficos 3D o programador pode usar Direct3D (DirectX) e OpenGL diretamente, se preferir. Mais recentemente, surgiu o [Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/) como uma alternativa ao [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/).

Tudo isso sem falar de Android e iOS, que devem possuir suas próprias APIs, como OpenGL ES.

No meio de tantas, pode ser difícil saber qual biblioteca é a base das outras e quais são apenas abstrações. Por isso se olhar os links acima para a wxWidgets, GTK, Cairo e SDL, pode ver que eu procurei colocar o link justamente para a página que explica sobre qual base a biblioteca é construída.

Answer (score 3):

Estou um pouco enferrujado com isto mas acho que ainda é assim:

```
#include <graphics.h>

int main() {
   initgraph();
   //faz alguma coisa aqui
   closegraph();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/Graph.c).

Veja as [funções disponíveis](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1126/materials/cppdoc/graphics.html) para fazer os desenhos. Eu só não me lembro se isto é padrão ou precisa de alguma biblioteca específica.

lembrando que isto é para uma aplicação console. Se for fazer em um sistema com um sistema próprio de telas, terá que usar a API do sistema operacional.

Outra possibilidade é acessar a placa gráfica de forma mais direta. Tem que ler a documentação dela. Não que as pessoas costumem fazer isto, mas é uma possibilidade. Em alguns casos basta escrever na memória gráfica. Esta é a forma para se criar uma biblioteca gráfica do nada. Ninguém faz isto. Ninguém recomenda isto. É o mesmo que dizer que vai fazer o sistema operacional porque não quer usar as *system calls* existentes.

Fora isto, a pergunta é muito ampla. Ninguém sai da total falta de noção de como começa para fazer algo tão complexo. Então para responder teria que escrever um livro (que por sinal acho que não existe)

Comment: Eu não entendi qual é o foco da sua pergunta. Não sei se você entendeu também qual é.

Answer (score 3):

Para colocar a coisa na devida perspectiva: nenhuma linguagem é inerentemente "gráfica" ou "texto". Em algum ponto, precisa haver uma inicialização para que o programa não seja cego, surdo e mudo. Essa preparação pode ser feita pelo próprio programa, ou pelo processo de carga que o precede.

No caso do C, pelo menos no UNIX/Linux, o processo de carga prepara o terreno, entregando o terminal de texto (stdin/stdout/stderr) já aberto.

Tal programa *pode* executar em modo gráfico, mas tem de invocar uma biblioteca gráfica explicitamente para "entrar em modo gráfico". No Linux há inúmeras bibliotecas para escolher: GTK+, Qt (para C++), Enlightenment, SDL, etc. O sistema não impõe uma biblioteca específica.

No caso do SDL, tudo começa chamando a função SDL_Init().

Daí pra frente, cada biblioteca tem seu próprio conjunto de métodos ou funções para lidar com primitivas gráficas (pixels, geometria, renderizar texto, etc.)